# Iterate while loop results to list in tcl

Tags: loops, while-loop, tcl

How to iterate while loop results to a list in Tcl?

```
set i 0
while { $i < ($num +1) } {
    set list $i
    incr i
}
```

create a list by using above while loop.

Comment: I suppose creating a list of integers is just an example, but if that's actually what you want to do, `package require struct::list ; struct::list iota [expr {$num + 1}]` will create one for you.

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it. You just need to use `lappend` inside the loop (and `for` is more idiomatic than `while` for this sort of thing). Note that where you put newlines is important; you *can't* put them between a `while` condition and the body of the loop (without putting a backslash in, which is ugly).

```
for {set i 0} {$i < ($num + 1)} {incr i} {
    lappend list $i
}
```

You could write the following equivalent code, but the above is clearer:

```
set i 0
while {$i < ($num + 1)} {
    lappend list $i
    incr i
}
```

Finally, I'd *actually* use this:

```
for {set i 0} {$i <= $num} {incr i} {
    lappend list $i
}
```

It emphasises that `$num` is the limit more clearly, with `<=` marking it as an *inclusive* limit. I'd do the same in many other languages too.

Answer (score 0):

$i takes a value that is always going to be a number as the code  is written. This  value is then assigned to  list. list  should then be printed or stored... exactly what you want to  do with list is not  clear because as the  code is written, it is simply overwritten on each iteration of the loop.

You also have  a problem with your loop condition possibly. Unless you are looking for a list of numbers generated by the increment of i the code should be:

```
set  i 0
while { i < ($num + 1)} {
    set list $i
    [here would be where you print/store list]
    incr i
}
```

Does this help?